# How to run consul agent in PCF alongside applications?

Tags: microservices, consul, cloud-foundry

How do I run a consul agent in Pivotal cloud foundry along with the application service (spring boot app / service and node.js app / service).

The following video provides an overview of using spring cloud starter consul to run it locally in machine (running an agent locally works). [Spring Cloud with Consul and Vault](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJUTIyvCd70&list=PLAdzTan_eSPQ1fuLSBhyB4eEZF7JQM0Mx&index=157)

My question is how to you run this in production / cloud environment. Appreciate any examples or approaches. Should it be done via docker or containers ? Appreciate any guideline.